# 2D plot markers TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to get the same markers as on the picture but they are not the same:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering  
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={$k$ Dimensions},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.75)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]

        \addplot[mark=o,blue] coordinates
        {(2,0.95268) (4,0.9435) (6,0.9390) (8,0.9421) (10,0.9371)(12, 0.9370) (14,0.9357) (16,0.9357) (18,0.9360) (20,0.9364) (22,0.9353) (24,0.9338) (26,0.9343)
            (28,0.9360)(30,0.9343)(32,0.9352)(34,0.9343)(36,0.9349)(38,0.9351) (40,0.9342)(42,0.9350)(44,0.9343)(46,0.9344) (48,0.9335) (50,0.9355)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Valiation}

        \addplot[mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=red}] coordinates
        {     (2, 0.9174) (4,0.8977) (6,0.8845) (8,0.8803) (10,0.8683)(12, 0.8606) (14, 0.8524) (16,0.8460) (18,0.8391) (20,0.8326) (22,0.8262) (24,0.8199) (26,0.8141)
            (28,0.8093)(30,0.8018)(32,0.7987)(34,0.7924)(36,0.7874)(38,0.7819) (40,0.7775)(42,0.7724)(44,0.7674)(46,0.7630) (48,0.7584) (50,0.7543)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Train}
        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

        \subcaption{ML 100K}
        \label{sub111}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny}},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={$k$ Dimensions},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.75)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]
        \addplot[mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=blue!50}] coordinates
        {(2,0.8943) (4,0.8816) (6,0.8751) (8,0.8713) (10,0.8691)(12, 0.8675) (14,0.8661) (16,0.8663) (18,0.8657) (20,0.8642) (22,0.8644) (24,0.8637) (26,0.8640)
            (28,0.8640)(30,0.8635)(32,0.8639)(34,0.8636)(36,0.8635)(38,0.8637) (40,0.8639)(42,0.8642)(44,0.8640)(46,0.8641) (48,0.8638) (50,0.8640)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Validation}

        \addplot[mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=red}] coordinates
        {     (2, 0.8780) (4,0.8569) (6,0.8428) (8,0.8326) (10,0.8249)(12, 0.8175) (14, 0.8114) (16,0.8063) (18,0.8010) (20,0.7950) (22,0.7909) (24,0.7860) (26,0.7821)
            (28,0.7780)(30,0.7737)(32,0.7700)(34,0.7655)(36,0.7615)(38,0.7587) (40,0.7548)(42,0.7510)(44,0.7481)(46,0.7442) (48,0.7405) (50,0.7372)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Train}

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}


        \subcaption{ML 1M}
        \label{marcost}

    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Bla}
    \label{tablex1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `mark size`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \centering  
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={$k$ Dimensions},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.75)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]

        \addplot[mark=o,blue,mark size=1pt] coordinates
        {(2,0.95268) (4,0.9435) (6,0.9390) (8,0.9421) (10,0.9371)(12, 0.9370) (14,0.9357) (16,0.9357) (18,0.9360) (20,0.9364) (22,0.9353) (24,0.9338) (26,0.9343)
            (28,0.9360)(30,0.9343)(32,0.9352)(34,0.9343)(36,0.9349)(38,0.9351) (40,0.9342)(42,0.9350)(44,0.9343)(46,0.9344) (48,0.9335) (50,0.9355)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Valiation}

        \addplot[mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=red,mark size=1.5pt,thin}] coordinates
        {     (2, 0.9174) (4,0.8977) (6,0.8845) (8,0.8803) (10,0.8683)(12, 0.8606) (14, 0.8524) (16,0.8460) (18,0.8391) (20,0.8326) (22,0.8262) (24,0.8199) (26,0.8141)
            (28,0.8093)(30,0.8018)(32,0.7987)(34,0.7924)(36,0.7874)(38,0.7819) (40,0.7775)(42,0.7724)(44,0.7674)(46,0.7630) (48,0.7584) (50,0.7543)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Train}
        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

        \subcaption{ML 100K}
        \label{sub111}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
        width=\linewidth,
        line width=0.5,
        grid=major, % Display a grid
        tick label style={font={\tiny}},
        legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape}},
        label style={font={\tiny }},
        legend image post style={},
        grid style={white},
        xlabel={$k$ Dimensions},
        ylabel={RMSE},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2
        },
        legend style={at={(1,0.75)}, anchor=north east,  draw=none, fill=none},
        ]
        \addplot[mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=blue!50,mark size=1.5pt,thin}] coordinates
        {(2,0.8943) (4,0.8816) (6,0.8751) (8,0.8713) (10,0.8691)(12, 0.8675) (14,0.8661) (16,0.8663) (18,0.8657) (20,0.8642) (22,0.8644) (24,0.8637) (26,0.8640)
            (28,0.8640)(30,0.8635)(32,0.8639)(34,0.8636)(36,0.8635)(38,0.8637) (40,0.8639)(42,0.8642)(44,0.8640)(46,0.8641) (48,0.8638) (50,0.8640)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Validation}

        \addplot[mark=diamond*,mark options={fill=red,mark size=1.5pt,thin}] coordinates
        {     (2, 0.8780) (4,0.8569) (6,0.8428) (8,0.8326) (10,0.8249)(12, 0.8175) (14, 0.8114) (16,0.8063) (18,0.8010) (20,0.7950) (22,0.7909) (24,0.7860) (26,0.7821)
            (28,0.7780)(30,0.7737)(32,0.7700)(34,0.7655)(36,0.7615)(38,0.7587) (40,0.7548)(42,0.7510)(44,0.7481)(46,0.7442) (48,0.7405) (50,0.7372)

        };
        \addlegendentry{Train}

        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}


        \subcaption{ML 1M}
        \label{marcost}

    \end{subfigure}

    \caption{Bla}
    \label{tablex1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW using standalone for something with subfigures may not be optimal.

Comment: Yes! You nailed it! Thank you very much!!! Chapeau.